# Query count and group by in cakephp 2.6.8

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, count, group-by

In cakephp 2.6.8, I am trying to query a table named "mytable" in order to count rows having common values.

So, this is my query :

```
$zone = $this->MyModel->find('all', array(
            'fields' => array('zone_id', 'COUNT(zone_id) as count'),
            'group' => 'zone_id'
        ));
```

Cakephp returns this result :

```
zone => array(
    0 => array(
          MyModel => array("zone_id" = 1) ),
          0 => array("count" = 77)
        ),
    1 => array(
          MyModel => array("zone_id" = 2) ),
          0 => array("count" = 55)
        ),
    2 => array(
          MyModel => array("zone_id" = 3) ),
          0 => array("count" = 23)
        )
);
```

All I need is something like this :

```
zone = array(
    0 => array("zone_id" => 1, "count" => 77),
    1 => array("zone_id" => 2, "count" => 55),
    2 => array("zone_id" => 3, "count" => 23)
);
```

How could I do to get this working without creating any Virtual Field?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I found a way to work this around with just PHP.

Comment: Can you provide us with how you did it?